# Getting Role Manager to work with an existing database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework and I'm trying to figure out how to get the Role Manager working. After I initially registered a user, triggering EF to build the user management / identity tables, I ended up moving them (AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles, AspNetUserRoles, AspNetUserClaims, and AspNetUserLogins) over to my existing database and setting the default connection to point there as well. All was fine and dandy until I decided I needed to implement the Role Manager and after adding the following entry to my web.config,

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="RoleManager">
    <providers>
      <add name="RoleManager"
           type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
           connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"
           applicationName="MyApp" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

and attempting to create a role (`Roles.CreateRole("Admin")` [Side question, is there any way to do this outside of code in VS 2013?]), I was faced with the error: `Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'`. So I naturally assumed the tables were not the only database objects that were generated, but after checking out the original mdf, turns out that indeed, that's all there was. I'm at a complete loss at this point and any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:** I've looked up solutions related to using the aspnet_reqsql tool to add Role Manager functionality, but the tables this generates seem incompatible. E.g., dbo.aspnet_Users instead of dbo.AspNetUsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the tables AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles, AspNetUserRoles, AspNetUserClaims, and AspNetUserLogins are part of the newer ASP.NET Identity system, whereas aspnet_Users, etc. are part of the old system (Membership I believe). `Roles.CreateRole` is from Membership, not Identity. For the Identity system, the `roleManager` web.config entry is unecessary, and a role would be created using `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.RoleManager`. E.g.,

```
RoleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new MyDbContext()));
var roleresult = RoleManager.Create(new IdentityRole(roleName));
```

Comment: Your assumptions are correct! To get identity working correctly you'll need to remove sections of your `web.config` that relate to old MembershipProvider.

Comment: @noelicus Cheers! It was certainly a head scratcher.